# Why can't I get my applet (on a Canvas) to work?

Tags: java, html, canvas, applet, invocationtargetexception

While making a game and putting it on a `Canvas` object, I use the following applet code:

```
package me.NoahCagle.game;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class GameApplet extends Applet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Game game = new Game();

public void init() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void start() {
    game.start();
}

public void stop() {
    game.stop();
}

}
```

HTML:

```
<applet archive="game.jar" code="me.NoahCagle.game.GameApplet" width="640" height="480"></applet>`
```

Then after I have this, I run it using Chrome, but this doesn't work. It throws me an InvocationTargetException

And the applet runs correctly in Eclipse.

Comment: can you share the stack trace?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: 1) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 2) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.